# Create graphs with limits on axis using seaborn/matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, nlp, seaborn, sentiment-analysis

I have a graph that has values between 0-40 on the x-axis and 0-20,000 on the y-axis. If I am plotting the graph, this is what I see,

[image]

Is it possible to plot the graph only till the points in the axis where data entries fall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can put limits till where the data could be shown using:
x limit as `matplotlib.pyplot.xlim(0, 40)` and y limit as `matplotlib.pyplot.ylim(0,20000)`